# Блокировка записи в ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть `ConcurrentHashMap` которая имеет следующий вид:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Domain, ConcurrentHashMap<Long, ServiceUser>>
```

В эту мапу пишутся значения из множества потоков, и так как она имеет еще вложеную мапу мне приходится ее создавать один раз в момент когда в определенный `Domain` ничего не писалось, конкретно в строке

```
this.userDirectory.put(domain, new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
```

Проблема заключается в том что  два несколько потоков в один  и тот же момент пытаются создать `ServiceUser` в одном и том же `Domain` и при этом они оба выполняют строку которую я указал выше, получаеться что код который должен был выполниться всего один раз выполняется  более двух раз. Проблема 
решается если сделать этот метод полностью `synchronized` но тогда получаеться что он будет `synchronized` всегда, в то время как это нужно всего лишь один раз.

**Вовпрос**: Каким образом я могу на какое то время заблокировать метод для остальных потоков так что бы не могли выполнить одно и тоже действие не используя `synchronized` в сигнатуре метода?

Вот исходный код метода:

```
public void addServiceUser(ServiceUser serviceUser) {

    Domain domain = serviceUser.getDomain();

    if (!this.userDirectory.containsKey(domain)){

        //это место выполняеться дважды
        this.userDirectory.put(domain, new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    }

    this.userDirectory.get(domain).put(serviceUser.getId(), serviceUser);
}
```

Пробовал сделать так но не помогло:

```
public  void addServiceUser(ServiceUser serviceUser) {

    Domain domain = serviceUser.getDomain();

    if (!this.userDirectory.containsKey(domain)){

        ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        lock.lock();

        try {
            this.userDirectory.put(domain, new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
        }finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }

    }

    this.userDirectory.get(domain).put(serviceUser.getId(), serviceUser);
}
```

Comment: [http://tsya.ru](http://tsya.ru)

Comment: map.putIfAbsent(domain, new ConcurrentHashMap<>())

Comment: Естественно такая блокировка не сработает, о локе же знает только вызывающий поток, ничто не помешает двум потокам создать два невзаимосвязанных лока и нахлестнусться друг на друга

Comment: @etki , прошу прощения за ошибки в словах, отговорка по этому поводу: русский - не мой родной язык, поэтому как могу.. По делу что нибудь можете добавить?